# Why does redirecting a file into itself clear its content?

Tags: bash, files

I expected the last command to return "test", but it does not.

```
foo@bar:~/docs$ echo "test" > test
foo@bar:~/docs$ cat test
test
foo@bar:~/docs$ cat test > test
foo@bar:~/docs$ cat test
foo@bar:~/docs$
```